# Is it ok to refer to frequentist statistics as traditional or classical statistics?

Tags: bayesian, frequentist

I don't know of any statisticians or work in the data science industry so I'm not really in the know about all the lingo.  I am trying to explain stats to others and was wondering if I could use the term "classical" or "traditional" instead of "frequentist", mainly because I do not like the word frequentist.  I am hoping to use the word classical or traditional whenever I want to contrast frequentist stats with Bayesian stats.

Thanks

Comment: The trouble you could encounter is if you use such terminology to refer to a modern frequentist technique. For the most part, though, you’re just doing some branding. Call it what gets your point across.

Comment: Why don't you like the word "frequentist"? It seems more descriptive than "classical" which could mean almost anything. E.g. I would not call random forests "classical".

Comment: Good point on not calling random forests classical.  Ok, I guess frequentist it is...

Answer (score 4):

In short, I'd say your safest using frequentist vs Bayesian. Classical is tricky from a historical perspective because "classical" Bayesian probability actually predates our "classical" frequentist statistical methods. Occasionally I'll hear people refer to frequentist Statistics as "Fisherian", but you're probably best avoiding that.

That said, I don't think anyone would turn up their nose at you using Classical vs Bayesian, but since you asked that's what I'd recommend.